is it sufficient to wash private part just with water
is it enough to wash private part just with water until madhy or mani is gone.
I mean when we wash our private part with water only there is traces of mani or madhi on tip area which can be removed by soap.
can i know is it sufficient to wash with water only without using soap or do we need to wash completely

In Allah's sharia, no one is expected to do anything beyond what he is able and capable of doing. Allah the Almighty says:

Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. ...
(2:286)

This is why for reaching that state of taharah (ritual purity) mainly only water is necessary as for the case of madhi it should be clear since we have enough evidence stating this, here just some out of of many:



'Ali reported:
I was one whose prostatic fluid flowed readily and I was ashamed to ask the Apostle (ﷺ) about it, because of the position of his daughter. I, therefore, asked Miqdad. b. al-Asad and he inquired of him (the Holy Prophet). He (the Holy Prophet) said: He should wash his male organ and perform ablution.
(Sahih Muslim)




It was narrated that 'Ali said:
"I was one who had a lot of prostatic discharge, and the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said to me: 'If you see Madhi (prostatic fluid) then wash your penis and perform Wudu' like that for Salah, but if you ejaculate semen, then perform Ghusl.'"
(Sunan an-Nasa-i)




Narrated Abdullah ibn Sa'd al-Ansari:
I asked the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) as to what makes it necessary to take a bath and about the (prostatic) fluid that flows after taking a bath. He replied: that is called madhi (prostatic fluid). It flows from every male. You should wash your private parts and testicles because of it and perform ablution as you do for prayer.
(Sunan abi Dawod)




It was narrated that Sulaiman bin Yasar said:
"Ali bin Abi Talib sent Al-Miqdad to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) to ask him about a man who notices Madhi. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: 'Let him wash his penis then perform Wudu'.'"
(Sunan an-Nasa-i)




It was narrated from Rafi' bin Khadij that 'Ali told 'Ammar to ask the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) about prostatic fluid, and he said:
'Let him wash his male member and perform Wudu'.'"
(Sunan an-Nasa-i)




'Ali said:
"I sent Al-Miqdad to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) to ask him about Madhi, and he said: 'Perform Wudu' and sprinkle water over your private part.'"
(Sunan an-Nasa-i)



Following this last hadith even washing is not necessary, but sprinkling it is enough.
